# How to restart a program

Tags: java, loops, input, sum

this program is done but I have a modification I would like to make. I am trying to make it restart after it finishes to take more input. I have tried to use a loop with a char but it seems to cause it to crash as a result of my array. I am currently investigating this, but I am posting as you may figure this out before me.
Thanks in advanced!

> EDIT: It has been solved now! Thanks all! The idea of changing it to a
>   string worked, which would explain the error. I appreciate all your
>   inputs!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class InputSum
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Initializes scanner

      int num=0;  //Creates array for input numbers
      int sum=0;
      char restart = 'y';
      List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

      while (restart == 'y') {
         System.out.print("Please input integers, note that -1 ends the submissions: "); 

         for(; ;)
         {
            num = scan.nextInt(); //Continues to read numbers and add them to the sum
            if (num == -1){
               break;
            }
            numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(num)); //Adds the values to the value of num to the array list
            sum += num; //Calculates the sum
            continue;  
         }
         System.out.print("The numbers entered are:    " + numbers); //Prints the numbers and the sum
         System.out.print("\nThe sum of the numbers is:  " + sum + "\n");
         System.out.print("Would you like to restart? Y or N: ");
         restart = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);  
      }
      System.out.print("The program has ended!");

   }
}
```

Comment: While the mega comments may be required for class, here they're somewhat distracting, and you might with to remove most of them.

Comment: Note that you never re-set the `numbers` variable at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah agree on the comments. Too many comments kill the comments. It's code, not litterature

Comment: Okay, I will remove the comments but yes they are required. Without all these comments you will get a 50% in the class. I am actually supposed to have them on every line. >< Edited!

Comment: @snipem1438 this is the kind of stupid requirements you'll get at school haha. Don't get too used to it, comments should be reserved to obscure code, and obscure code should be rare

Comment: OK, now you say that the code "crashes", but could you be much more specific? What exactly happens? Does it close and send an exception message? Does it insult your mother and make you write bad checks? What?

Comment: It crashs because your trying to use .charAt(0). and the string is empty at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Initializes scanner

  int num=0;  //Creates array for input numbers
  int sum=0;
  String restart ="y";
  List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //Creates array list for input

  while (restart.equals("y")) {
     System.out.print("Please input integers, note that -1 ends the submissions: "); //Prompts the user for input

     num=0;
     sum=0;         
     numbers.clear();

     for(; ;)
     {
        num = scan.nextInt(); //Continues to read numbers and add them to the sum
        if (num == -1){
           break;
        }
        numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(num)); //Adds the values to the value of num to the array list
        sum += num; //Calculates the sum
        continue;  
     }
     System.out.print("The numbers entered are:    " + numbers); //Prints the numbers and the sum
     System.out.print("\nThe sum of the numbers is:  " + sum + "\n");
     System.out.print("Would you like to restart? Y or N: ");
     restart = scan.next();  
  }

  System.out.print("The program has ended!");
```

use scan.next instead of scan.nextLine() and reset num, sum and numbers. num = 0, sum =0. numbers.clear();

Comment: It works! Thanks, Jawad! I was just about to try a string, I don't know why I didn't think to try it first!